# importing pywiiuse to test out

Tags: python, python-2.7

### This is probably a simple problem. But I downloaded the pywiiuse library from [here](http://code.google.com/p/pywiiuse/) and I also downloaded the examples. However when I try to run one of the examples I end up with import issues. I'm not certain I have everything configured properly to run. One error I receive when trying to run example.py:

```
Press 1&2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 73, in <module>
    wiimotes = wiiuse.init(nmotes)
  File "/home/thed0ctor/Descargas/wiiuse-0.12/wiiuse/__init__.py", line 309, in init
    dll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libwiiuse.so')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 431, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libwiiuse.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

---

I'm really just starting out with this library and don't really see any documentation on how to configure pywiiuse so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The pywiiuse library is a Python wrapper for the [wiiuse C library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wiiuse/).

Before you can use the wrapper you will first need to install the library it wraps, choose the newest version from [this download page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wiiuse/files/wiiuse/) and download the appropriate installation package for you system (probably the .tar.gz since you appear to be on Linux).

Comment: Hey I read the readme on this library and it said to do a make but I receive this error when trying to make the file:'make[1]: se ingresa al directorio «/home/thed0ctor/wiiuse_v0.12/src»
gcc -Wall -pipe -fPIC -funroll-loops -O2 -I. -c classic.c -o release-/classic.o
In file included from classic.c:43:0:
wiiuse_internal.h:49:34: error fatal: bluetooth/bluetooth.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio
compilación terminada.
make[1]: *** [release-/classic.o] Error 1
make[1]: se sale del directorio «/home/thed0ctor/wiiuse_v0.12/src»
make: *** [all] Error 2'

It basically can't find this bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

add the link of libwiiuse.so to /usr/local/lib.

I also ran into this situation, I konw why it happies, but I don't konw the deep reason.